# Error Connecting to Substrate Connection to websocket 'ws://127.0.0.1:9944/' failed

Tags: substrate-front-end

When running the tutorial for substrate-frontend-template in Chrome/macOS, it doesn't load due to a websocket error.   The tutorial says to use "yarn start" which invokes: "react-app-rewired start"

Tutorial:
[https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/get-started/build-local-blockchain/#:~:text=yarn%20install-,Start%20the%20front%2Dend%20template,-The%20Substrate%20front](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/get-started/build-local-blockchain/#:%7E:text=yarn%20install-,Start%20the%20front%2Dend%20template,-The%20Substrate%20front)

where section is "Start the front-end template"

Comment: Is the local node still running?  
It mentions `./target/release/node-template --dev` futher up.

Comment: That was it.  Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding comment from Oliver as answer ( so this question don't stay "unanswered"):
You have to make sure that node is still running on same port as you are trying to connect

Comment: Thanks, did not see it!