# Error Connecting to Substrate Connection to websocket 'ws://127.0.0.1:9944/' failed substrate-frontend-template

Tags: error

#### Description of bug

I was trying to follow this tutorial https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/get-started/build-local-blockchain/#install-the-front-end-template but after doing `yarn start` I get the error "Error Connecting to Substrate Connection to websocket 'ws://127.0.0.1:9944/' failed." on http://localhost:8000/

Doing `yarn install` also gives me those warnings if they are relevant

```
➤ YN0000: ┌ Resolution step
➤ YN0002: │ eslint-config-react-app@npm:7.0.0 [9c894] doesn't provide @babel/plugin-syntax-flow (p4202d), requested by eslint-plugin-flowtype
➤ YN0002: │ eslint-config-react-app@npm:7.0.0 [9c894] doesn't provide @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx (pb90d4), requested by eslint-plugin-flowtype
➤ YN0002: │ react-dev-utils@npm:12.0.0 doesn't provide typescript (p08c91), requested by fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin
➤ YN0002: │ react-dev-utils@npm:12.0.0 doesn't provide webpack (pf80ce), requested by fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin
➤ YN0002: │ react-scripts@npm:5.0.0 [9c894] doesn't provide autoprefixer (p5a5c8), requested by tailwindcss
➤ YN0002: │ substrate-front-end-template@workspace:. doesn't provide webpack (p9e29f), requested by node-polyfill-webpack-plugin
➤ YN0000: │ Some peer dependencies are incorrectly met; run yarn explain peer-requirements <hash> for details, where <hash> is the six-letter p-prefixed code
➤ YN0000: └ Completed in 0s 227ms
➤ YN0000: ┌ Fetch step
➤ YN0000: └ Completed in 0s 577ms
➤ YN0000: ┌ Link step
➤ YN0076: │ fsevents@patch:fsevents@npm%3A2.3.2#~builtin<compat/fsevents>::version=2.3.2&hash=18f3a7 The linux-x64 architecture is incompatible with this module, link skipped.
➤ YN0000: └ Completed in 0s 853ms
➤ YN0000: Done with warnings in 1s 760ms
```

```
Im on wsl2 Ubuntu 22.04.01 LTS
yarn version: 3.1.1
node version: v16.14.0
npm version: 9.1.2
```

#### Steps to reproduce

```
git clone https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-front-end-template
cd substrate-front-end-template
yarn install
yarn start
```

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/3942/error-connecting-to-substrate-connection-to-websocket-ws-127-0-0-19944-fai

Comment: oh lol thanks it works now